# Is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ a Euclidean domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How do I prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is or isn't a Euclidean domain?

So if $F$ is a field, then $F[X]$ is a Euclidean domain. I don't see why this means that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is a Euclidean domain, because we have $\sqrt{2}$ instead of $X$.

Comment: Well, it is a field.

Comment: Perhaps you mean $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$?

Comment: I know it is a field. And no I mean $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$

Comment: But every field is a Euclidean domain. The question usually is for $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$.

Comment: Any field is a Euclidean domain relative to any norm because $a=(ab^{-1})b+0$ and $N(0)=0\leq N(b)$. So one can theoretically raise the question but it is a dead end.

Comment: Okay it is a Euclidean domain because it is a field. What Euclidean function can I apply on it?

Comment: Read my comment. It works with any Euclidean function (or norm)

Comment: Oh I see. Pretty stupid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every field is a Euclidean domain with Euclidean function $E(x)=1$ (or any function really) because every division leaves a zero remainder.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I thought the function had to be surjective, so now I understand my problem.